# Python - creating a matrix of normal distribution columns where each row sums to 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, math

I am working with some election data using pandas. I would like to know how votes from party A would transfer to parties B and C in each of the 650 seats if party A did not exist.

We assume that we know that nationally:

- to_B: 48% transfer to party B
- to_C: 32% would transfer to party C
- to_dnv: 20% would not vote

I am looking to generate a normal distribution of numbers between 0 and 1 for each seat, where:

1. The sum of each row sums to 1
2. The average of column to_B is 0.48
3. The average of column to_C is 0.32
4. The average of column to_dnvis 0.2

As an example with completely separate numbers:

| seat | to_B | to_C | to_dnv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.5 | 0.3 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 0.1 | 0.6 | 0.3 |
| 3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.4 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 650 | etc | etc | etc |

Here in this manual example:

- All rows sum to 1
- The average of to_B is 0.3, which we would have defined before generation.
- The average of to_C is 0.4, which we would have defined before generation.
- The average of to_dnv is 0.3, which we would have defined before generation.

The motivation is such that later I zip together this table with another separate table I have already built which contains the election results of each seat. Then I will use these normally distributed numbers to redistribute party A's votes into party B, C and DNV.

What is the best way to go about generating such a matrix? Preferably in Pandas.

Code so far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue May 11 20:23:45 2021

@author: Josh
"""

## IMPORTS

import numpy
import pandas
import sys
import re

## README 
'''
Prerequirement: Create a folder called Data and put it in the same folder as this script. Download the 2019 results csv ("HoC-GE2019-results-by-constituency-csv HoC-GE2019-results-by-constituency-csv (126 KB, Excel Spreadsheet)(126 KB, Excel Spreadsheet)" from the Commons Library and place it in the Data folder: https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/cbp-8749/ 
'''

'''
Steps:
    1. Read in 2019 results to a raw numpy array
    2. Construct a normal distrubution of 650 ways to redistribute LibDem vote share, 
        around 20% do not transfer
        around 48% transfer to Labour
        around 32% transfer to Conservatives 
    3. Zip this redistribution together with the 2019 results. Compare number of seats before and after to see how seats would change.
    4. Convert to voter percentage array
    5. Run this simulation 1000 times, find the average seat numbers 
'''

# Config
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', sys.maxsize)
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', sys.maxsize)
pandas.set_option('display.width', sys.maxsize)

# Variables
parties = ["con", "lab", "ld", "brexit", "green", "snp", "pc", "dup", "sf", "sdlp", "uup", "alliance", "other"]

raw_results_path = 'Data/HoC-GE2019-results-by-constituency-csv.csv'
dtype_dic = {party: int for party in parties}

## STEP 1
raw_results = pandas.io.parsers.read_csv(raw_results_path, dtype = dtype_dic)#.values

## STEP 2
# ??

## STEP 3
# ??

## STEP 4
# Calculate vote shares of each party

for party in parties:
    raw_results["Share_" + party] = raw_results[party] / raw_results["valid_votes"]

print(raw_results)
```

Comment: Do you already have an attempt (partially working or otherwise) coded up? If so, it'd be nice to share it, so that people can propose improvements to your code

Comment: I've actually got no clue where to begin with the next part of this problem. Unfortunately it is quite mathsy and a little bit outside my expertise. But I have now edited the post with the code I have so far, which I hope will better show the context of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like [np.random.dirichlet](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.dirichlet.html#numpy-random-dirichlet) could work here:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Set Seed for reproducibility (Remove if different randoms are needed)
np.random.seed(5)
# Create Dirichlet Distribution
a = np.random.dirichlet((.48, .32, .2), size=600)

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['to_B', 'to_C', 'to_dnv'])
df = df.rename_axis('seat')
```

Frame

```
print(df)

          to_B      to_C    to_dnv
seat                              
0     0.553653  0.092384  0.353963
1     0.970484  0.029512  0.000005
2     0.897923  0.040126  0.061951
3     0.937764  0.052244  0.009991
4     0.123293  0.000047  0.876660
...        ...       ...       ...
595   0.430808  0.017738  0.551454
596   0.000072  0.034152  0.965775
597   0.616199  0.290054  0.093747
598   0.922872  0.075728  0.001400
599   0.190437  0.756399  0.053163

[600 rows x 3 columns]
```

Row Sums

```
print(df.sum(axis=1))

seat
0      1.0
1      1.0
2      1.0
3      1.0
4      1.0
      ... 
595    1.0
596    1.0
597    1.0
598    1.0
599    1.0
Length: 600, dtype: float64
```

Column Means

```
print(df.mean(axis=0))

to_B      0.473463
to_C      0.317920
to_dnv    0.208617
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Bravo! +1. I've a (similar) solution with `scipy.stats.truncnorm` and `rvs` but the Dirichlet distribution is perfect here!

Comment: Amazing! That's perfect, thank you very much

Comment: Although, I have looked at the distributions made with this and it seems to be the opposite of a normal distribution. Where this first example should have an average of roughly 0.3, and the second an average of 0.5, it seems to achieve this by piling up at the extremes: 

https://imgur.com/a/ZRnuWHX

Any other suggestions to ensure this is normal?

Comment: @Corralien I would still be interested in seeing your solution, if you have one :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

The answer above by Henry Ecker is definitely the better solution here. Leaving this one up in case anyone finds it useful.

#### Original solution

Alright so I have something that seems to work, but probably isn't mathematically sound.

The idea is to generate two normally distributed random variable lists for a and b, and fill it up to 1 for c.

```py
import numpy as np

# generate data for A and B
# scale is the std. dev. and can be tweaked to fit the task
a = np.random.normal(loc=0.48, scale=0.05, size=650)
b = np.random.normal(loc=0.32, scale=0.05, size=650)

# now to generate C, we can't use the same approach as this would not sum to 1 all the time (obviously)
# instead, we fill the column up to 1
c = 1 - a - b

# this should end up close to 0.2
print(np.average(c))
```

When running it 100 times, the calculated average always ends up between `0.19450` and `0.20521` for me, which may or may not be good enough for your use case.

Note that sometimes negative values are generated if the average is small and/or the standard deviation is large. Depending on the requirements this solution may help or inspire you :)

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! Much appreciated. I forgot to mention that all distributions should be between 0 and 1. Perhaps there is a way to normalise the columns horizontally such that they are all between 0 and 1, but I'm not sure if that would break the vertical normal distributions.